# How to get two or four figures in the same size?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I give an example for describing this problem.

```
f[x_] := Sin[x];
p1 = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,FrameStyle -> Black, 
FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.5, 1}, None}, {{0, 1, 2, 3}, None}}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.003]], 
PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-0.1, 1}},FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 18], 
Style["y", FontSize ->18]}, RotateLabel -> False]

g[x_] := Cos[x];
p2 = Plot[g[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,FrameStyle -> Black, 
FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.5, 1}, None}, {{0, 1, 2, 3}, None}}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.003]], 
PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-0.1, 1}}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 18], 
Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(log\), \(100\)]\)y", FontSize -> 18]},
RotateLabel -> False]
```

These are two figures, p1 and p2. I try to use "GraphicsGrid", but I get it like:

```
p3 = GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}}, ImageSize -> 800, Spacings -> {5, 1}, 
Alignment -> Right, ItemAspectRatio -> 0.7]
```

[image]
How can I plot them in the same borderlayout? If there are four figures, how can I plot them in the style of two rows and two columns? Thanks.

**Edit:**
I have one more question:
If I want to get a two by two grid of plots, but the labels of the first two are FrameLabel -> {None,Style["y"]} , FrameLabel -> None. And the last two are FrameLabel -> {Style["x"],Style["y"]}, FrameLabel -> {Style["x"],None}.
I only want to keep the same size in frames. My way is FrameLabel -> {Style["x",White],Style["y"]}, but the the red region is too wide, like
[image]

```
p5 = GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}}, Spacings -> {5, 0},
Alignment ->Right, ItemAspectRatio -> 0.7]

f[x_] := Sin[x];
p1 = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,FrameStyle -> Black, 
FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.5, 1}, None}, {{0, 1, 2, 3}, None}}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.003]],
PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-0.1, 1}}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 18, White], 
Style["y", FontSize -> 18]}, RotateLabel -> False, 
ImageSize -> {Automatic,200}]

g[x_] := Cos[x];
p2 = Plot[g[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,FrameStyle -> Black, 
FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.5, 1}, None}, {{0, 1, 2, 3}, None}}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.003]], 
PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-0.1, 1}}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 18, White], 
Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(log\), \(100\)]\)y", FontSize -> 18]},
RotateLabel -> False, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 200}]

m[x_] := Cot[x];
p3 = Plot[m[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,FrameStyle -> Black, 
FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.5, 1}, None}, {{0, 1, 2, 3}, None}}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.003]], 
PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-0.1, 1}}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 18], 
Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(log\), \(100\)]\)y", FontSize -> 18]},
RotateLabel -> False, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 200}]

n[x_] := Tan[x];
p4 = Plot[n[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,FrameStyle -> Black, 
FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.5, 1}, None}, {{0, 1, 2, 3}, None}}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.003]], 
PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-0.1, 1}}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 18], 
Style["y", FontSize -> 18]}, RotateLabel -> False, 
ImageSize -> {Automatic, 200}]
```

Another one is like

[image]

```
p6 = GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}},Spacings -> {0, 0}, 
Alignment -> Right, ItemAspectRatio -> 0.7]
```

Comment: `Graphics` + hit F1 -> Options -> ImageSize/ImagePadding/ImageMarings.

Answer (score 3):

It is the interaction of a number of things that's causing the size difference. But one simple solution is just to remove `ItemAspectRatio -> 0.7'. Then

```
p3 = GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}}, ImageSize -> 800, Spacings -> {5, 1}, Alignment -> Right]
```

gives

[image]

Another way of looking at what's happening is that your original figures `p1` and `p2` are being drawn the same width. But to make the `log_100 y` axis label in `p2` fit into that width, the rest of the plot is shrunk. So another way to deal with it is to force both of the original images to be drawn to the same height by adding

```
ImageSize -> {Automatic, 250}
```

to the options for `p1` and `p2`. You can then include `ItemAspectRatio -> 0.7` in the options for `p3` and the result is the same as the figure above.

Showing a two by two grid of plots is done simply by creating a "matrix" of plots and then using `GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}}]' (as detailed in the documentation for`GraphicsGrid').

Comment: Thank you for your help.